# Zero-length file in S3 folder possibly prevents accessing that folder with Hive?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hive, hdfs

I cannot access a folder on AWS S3 with Hive, presumably, a zero-length file in that directory is the reason. AWS management console's folder is a zero-byte object with key that ends with a slash, i.e. "folder_name/". I think that Hive or Hadoop may have a bug in how they define a folder scheme on S3.

Here is what I have done.

```
    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE is_data_original (user_id STRING, action_name STRING, timestamp STRING) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'  STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION 's3n://bucketname/logs/';

    SELECT * FROM is_data_original LIMIT 10;
```

Failed with exception java.io.IOException:java.lang.NullPointerException

```
username@client:~$ hadoop fs -ls s3n://bucketname/logs/
Found 4 items
-rwxrwxrwx   1          0 2015-01-22 20:30 /logs/data
-rwxrwxrwx   1       8947 2015-02-27 18:57 /logs/data_2015-02-13.csv
-rwxrwxrwx   1       7912 2015-02-27 18:57 /logs/data_2015-02-14.csv
-rwxrwxrwx   1      16786 2015-02-27 18:57 /logs/data_2015-02-15.csv

hadoop fs -mkdir s3n://bucketname/copylogs/
hadoop fs -cp s3n://bucketname/logs/*.csv s3n://bucketname/copylogs/

username@client:~$ hadoop fs -ls s3n://bucketname/copylogs/
Found 3 items
-rwxrwxrwx   1       8947 2015-02-28 05:09 /copylogs/data_2015-02-13.csv
-rwxrwxrwx   1       7912 2015-02-28 05:09 /copylogs/data_2015-02-14.csv
-rwxrwxrwx   1      16786 2015-02-28 05:09 /copylogs/data_2015-02-15.csv

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE is_data_copy (user_id STRING, action_name STRING, timestamp STRING) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'  STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION 's3n://bucketname/copylogs/';

SELECT * FROM is_data_copy LIMIT 10;
```

The latter, after copying, works fine.

Below two commands both work:

```
hadoop fs -cat s3n://bucketname/logs/data_2015-02-15.csv
hadoop fs -cat s3n://bucketname/copylogs/data_2015-02-15.csv
```

Versions: **Hive 0.11.0** and **Hadoop 1.0.3.**

Is this some kind of bug? Is it related to AWS S3? Any ideas? I need to be able to read the original location, because this is where that data keeps flowing.

I have no control on the processes that created the directory and placed log files in there, so I cannot check anything on that end.

---

I carried an experiment: created a key/folder on S3 and placed a file in there in two different ways: using AWS Management Console and using hadoop fs.
I can see a zero-byte file in the folder in case I used AWS Console and I am getting a null-pointer exception assessing it with Hive. With hadoop fs I don't have such a problem. I assume, that zero-byte file supposed to be deleted but it was not in case of AWS Console. I am sure, that in my case, s3 folder is not created from AWS console, but possibly Ruby or Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a Hive bug. Hive 0.12.0 does not have that problem.